# How to crop a mp4 video on a website

Tags: html, video, mp4

I am trying to play a mp4 on the main page of my website. I have a sample mp4 below to test with ..... but I would like to keep it width 100% which is does,  but remove a certain percentage of the top and bottom so I have a thinner video. Below keep it responsive but I need to reduce the top and bottom by say 10%

```
<div >
    <div >

    <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 " style="background-color:red;">

    <video id="video01" autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item"
    style="background-color:green;">
    <source src="http://elevationchurch.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Website_GetInvolved_v3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think SVG Masking is a solution. You can read about it here : http://svglab.com/exp/masking-video.html